# Updating status bar style on an existing home screen app

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, ios7, mobile-website

I have a web app targeted for mobile use (using `apple-mobile-web-app-capable`). I initially omitted the `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style` meta tag, as I the default (iOS 6) behaviour worked fine. However, in iOS 7, the omission of this meta tag triggers different behaviour i.e. the status bar is just black.

I've now added:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

but this only appears to take effect if you re-add the web app to the home screen—web apps added to the home screen before this change still have a black status bar.

Is there anyway to update the status bar style without having to remove and re-add the app?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this meta tag does not work on iOS7, have you tried to change it to black-translucent, or default? it works on iOS8 though